# Converting inserted string to a compilable expression

Tags: java, string, compiler-construction, expression

I'm somehow new to Java so my question can seem trivial, however i cannot find an answer to it anywhere in my books.

I want to initiatie a dialog with a user in which he would enter an arithmetic expression (ex. (2*x+y)) And then print  out the result for such expression (for given values of x and y)

```
    String EXPRESION = null;
    EXPRESION = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter expresion for dy/dx");
    double x = 1.4;
    double y = 5;
    double output = HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The value is" +output);
```

I fail to convert the string inserted by the user so it would serve as an arithmetic expression for x and y and hence define the value for output

TIA
JMT

Answer (score 4):

It isn't so hard to parse them yourself, but if you need fast and probably accurate result, you can use one of the existing libraries to parse arithmetic expressions, like [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) or perhaps that [Simple Parser for Arithmetic Expressions](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/Java2/Exp/).

See the [Jep Console](http://www.singsurf.org/djep/jep.html) for a sample.
It looks like Jep is payware. It might not be a problem, otherwise as I wrote, you should be able to find a number of equivalent libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write an expression parser to accomplish this kind of behaviour. There are a number of ways to accomplish this:

1. Write your own expression parser using e.g. ANTLR.
2. Include a scripting language (Jython, Beanshell, JavaScript...) and use that to parse and evaluate the expressions. The Java Scripting API can show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native facility in Java for evaluating strings as expressions.  You must therefore do the work yourself.

If you just want a quick and dirty solution, Javassist includes a snippet compiler allowing you to define a new class with your expression, and invoke it to get your result, after which you can discard it (i.e. run it in a separate classloader).  It will require some work though :)

http://www.jboss.org/javassist/

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at JScheme. Need to compile & run with the jscheme jar file.

```
import jscheme.JS; 

String query = "(+ 10 20)";
System.out.println(query + " = " + JS.eval(query));
```

See third example down at http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/doc/userman.html#si

JScheme main page at http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/main.html

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert a String into Arithmetic Expression**

```
import bsh.*;

 class Operation
 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        Interpreter i=new Interpreter();
        int r=(Integer)i.eval(args[0]);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

for this we need a separate jar file named: bsh.jar file

need to set classpath for above jar file

source:
http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-convert-string-into-arithmetic.html